# Windows 7 mouse cursor animation doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, cursor

On my notebook I do not see any cursor animation (mouse pointers are visible but not animating), although all settings are correct. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its the touch pad driver casuing this issue.

Update your touch pad driver and you should be sweet :)

hope it helps

Comment: Uninstalling the Dell touch pad driver has worked!

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure you're using the right cursors, then it might be a problem with the video driver.

I suggest that you go to the **manufacturer's website** and search for a Windows 7 driver for your video card. I emphasis that you should find a Windows 7 driver, and not a Vista driver.

If you have done this and installed a Windows 7 driver but cursor animation still doesn't work, please let me know the exact model of the card and I'll search further.

If for some reason you can't manage to identify your card, use [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/).

**EDIT**

Since you're using an Inter chipset, you can use the [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/detect.htm) to analyse your system (installing a secure ActiveX/Java browser component is required).

Comment: Thanks for the hint: I've, indeed, recently installed a new video driver. GPU-Z's output: http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/10/01/18/9cv.png.

Comment: See my edit. What are the results of the analysis?

Comment: According to the Intel Driver Update Utility my driver is current. This is the site where the latest driver was installed from.

Comment: It seems that your video driver doesn't support it, for the moment. Check periodically for new updates (Windows Update also does a good job there), and you might strike it lucky in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the default, animated cursors? There are older cursor themes that are not animated at all. You should check and see if it's the case.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the default animated cursors.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. If I change Cursor-Theme for and back it works. After a reboot the icon isn't animated anymore.

Working with a lenovo thinkpad r61 and win7 Professional. Nvidia-Video-Card-driver is on the current state.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: did you check touchpad / mouse drivers? This fixed it for others.